# QListView height according to contents

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt4

I have a QListView with a list of strings.

Basically, I use it as pop window for a QLineEdit for an autocomplete process.
I dont want the QListView to display blank lines, only lines that have strings in it.
See this:
[image]

I want it to resize itself automatically so it wont have these blank rows after the last entry.

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at QCompleter? That should do what you want.

Comment: I'm not trying to auto-complete, I'm trying to avoid having these blank lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to do this: Reimplement [QListView::rowsInserted()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qlistview.html#rowsInserted) method class. Say you have MyListView inherited from QListView. So the code can look like this:

```
void MyListView::rowsInserted ( const QModelIndex & parent, int start, int end )
{
    QListView::rowsInserted(parent, start, end);
    int rc = model()->rowCount();

    // use this all the rows have the same height. otherwise
    // you will need to iterate and sum all row heights
    resize(width(), rc ? rc*sizeHintForRow(0): height()); 
}
```

But to do it simpler, I'd recommend you to use [QCompleter](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qcompleter.html) class [with QLineEdit](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qlineedit.html#setCompleter). Its already designed for what you need and you don't need to spend time trying to make it work.

Comment: Well, I used 'resize(width(), rc ? rc*sizeHintForRow(0): height());' in paintEvent method and seems like it did the trick.